# How to serve image from gcs using python 2.7 standard app engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

The following code is almost verbatim copy of the sample code from Google to serve a file from Google Cloud Storage via Python 2.7 App Engine Standard Environment.  When serving locally with command:

> dev_appserver.py --default_gcs_bucket_name darianhickman-201423.appspot.com

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
import webapp2

class LogoPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    bucket_name = "darianhickman-201423.appspot.com"
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    self.response.headers['Message'] = "LogoPage"
    gcs_file = gcs.open("/"+ bucket_name +'/logo.jpg')
    contents = gcs_file.read()
    gcs_file.close()
    self.response.body.(contents)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/logo.jpg', LogoPage),
                               ('/logo2.jpg', LogoPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

The empty body message I see on the console is:

```
NotFoundError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 404.
Path: '/darianhickman-201423.appspot.com/logo.jpg'.
Request headers: None.
Response headers: {'date': 'Sun, 30 Dec 2018 18:54:54 GMT', 'connection': 'close', 'server': 'Development/2.0'}.
Body: ''.
Extra info: None.
```

Again this is almost identical to read logic documented at 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

If you serve it locally using `dev_appserver.py`, it runs a local emulation of Cloud Storage and does not connect to the actual Google Cloud Storage.

Try writing a file and then reading it. You’ll see that it will succeed.

Here is a sample:

```
import os
import cloudstorage as gcs
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    filename = "/" + bucket_name + "/testfile"

#Create file    
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                        'w',
                        content_type='text/plain')
    gcs_file.write('Hello world\n')
    gcs_file.close()

#Read file and display content    
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
    contents = gcs_file.read()
    gcs_file.close()
    self.response.write(contents)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Run it with `dev_appserver.py --default_gcs_bucket_name a-local-bucket .`

If you deploy your application on Google App Engine then it will work (assuming you have a file called **logo.jpg** uploaded) because it connects to Google Cloud Storage. I tested it with minor changes:

```
import os
import cloudstorage as gcs
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import webapp2

class LogoPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
    #or you can use bucket_name = "<your-bucket-name>"
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    self.response.headers['Message'] = "LogoPage"
    gcs_file = gcs.open("/"+ bucket_name +'/logo.jpg')
    contents = gcs_file.read()
    gcs_file.close()
    self.response.write(contents)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', LogoPage)], debug=True)
```

Also, It's worth mentioning that the documentation for [Using the client library with the development app server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#using_the_client_library_with_the_development_app_server) seems to be outdated, it states that:

> There is no local emulation of Cloud Storage, all requests to read and
>   write files must be sent over the Internet to an actual Cloud Storage
>   bucket.

The team responsible for the documentation has already been informed about this issue.